# Python Merge columns into one column by duplicating date indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I want to merge columns into one column by adding rows with the same index. Of course, the index is the date. Then I want to plot the `seaborn` plots.

My data:

```
df = 
              A    B    # A, B two unique groups, denote 36, 24 size
timestamp                       
2019-10-01   10   20
2019-10-02   30   40
```

Expected answer:

```
df = 
            val    group   size    # A, B denote 36, 24 size
timestamp                       
2019-10-01   10    A       34
2019-10-01   20    B       24
2019-10-02   30    A       34
2019-10-02   40    B       24
```

My code:

I have no idea how to proceed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `melt`

```
out = df.reset_index().melt('timestamp')
Out[73]: 
    timestamp variable  value
0  2019-10-01        A     10
1  2019-10-02        A     30
2  2019-10-01        B     20
3  2019-10-02        B     40
```